# Java+DOM: How do I set the base namespace of an (already created) Document?

Tags: java, xml, dom, namespaces, document

I am dealing with an **already created** Document object.
I have to be able to set it's base namespace (attribute name "xmlns") to certain value.
My input is DOM and is something like:

```
<root>...some content...</root>
```

What I need is DOM which is something like:

```
<root xmlns="myNamespace">...some content...</root>
```

That's it. Easy, isn't it? **Wrong! Not with DOM!**

## I have tried the following:

#### 1) Using doc.getDocumentElement().setAttribute("xmlns","myNamespace")

I get a document with empty xmlns (it works on **any** other attribute name!)

```
<root xmlns="">...</root>
```

#### 2) Using renameNode(...)

First **clone** the document:

```
Document input = /*that external Document whose namespace I want to alter*/;

DocumentBuilderFactory BUILDER_FACTORY_NS = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
BUILDER_FACTORY_NS.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document output = BUILDER_NS.newDocument();
output.appendChild(output.importNode(input.getDocumentElement(), true));
```

*I'm really missing document.clone(), but perhaps it's just me.*

Now **rename the root node**:

```
output.renameNode(output.getDocumentElement(),"myNamespace",
    output.getDocumentElement().getTagName());
```

Now isn't **that** straightforward? ;)

What I get now is:

```
<root xmlns="myNamespace">
    <someElement xmlns=""/>
    <someOtherElement xmlns=""/>
</root>
```

So *(as all of us have expected, right?)*, this renames the namespace **only of the the root node**.

*Curse you, DOM!*

Is there any way to do this recursively (without writing an own recursive method)?

#### Please help ;)

Please don't advice me to do some fancy workaround, such as transforming DOM to
something else, alter the namespace there, and transform it back.
I need DOM because it's the fastest standard way to manipulate XML.

Note: I'm using the latest JDK.

**EDIT**
Removed wrong assumptions from the question, which had to do with namespace *prefix*.

Comment: Changing a namespace of a node is like writing an article, set a language property  and expect it to be translated. You would have to translate the words. 
So, the "clean way" is to recreate the nodes in a second document using a recursive function.

Answer (score 11):

I had the very same problem today. I ended up using parts of [@ivan_ivanovich_ivanoff answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492428/javadom-how-do-i-set-the-base-namespace-of-an-already-created-document/1492867#1492867) but removed the recursion and fixed some bugs.

**Very important:** if old namespace is `null` you must add two translations, one from `null` to your new `namespaceURI` and another from `""` to your new `namespaceURI`. This happens because the first call to `renameNode` will change existing nodes that have a `null` `namespaceURI` to `xmlns=""`.

Example of usage:

```
Document xmlDoc = ...;

new XmlNamespaceTranslator()
    .addTranslation(null, "new_ns")
    .addTranslation("", "new_ns")
    .translateNamespaces(xmlDoc);

// xmlDoc will have nodes with namespace null or "" changed to "new_ns"
```

Full source code follows:

```
public  class XmlNamespaceTranslator {

    private Map<Key<String>, Value<String>> translations = new HashMap<Key<String>, Value<String>>();

    public XmlNamespaceTranslator addTranslation(String fromNamespaceURI, String toNamespaceURI) {
        Key<String> key = new Key<String>(fromNamespaceURI);
        Value<String> value = new Value<String>(toNamespaceURI);

        this.translations.put(key, value);

        return this;
    }

    public void translateNamespaces(Document xmlDoc) {
        Stack<Node> nodes = new Stack<Node>();
        nodes.push(xmlDoc.getDocumentElement());

        while (!nodes.isEmpty()) {
            Node node = nodes.pop();
            switch (node.getNodeType()) {
            case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                Value<String> value = this.translations.get(new Key<String>(node.getNamespaceURI()));
                if (value != null) {
                    // the reassignment to node is very important. as per javadoc renameNode will
                    // try to modify node (first parameter) in place. If that is not possible it
                    // will replace that node for a new created one and return it to the caller.
                    // if we did not reassign node we will get no childs in the loop below.
                    node = xmlDoc.renameNode(node, value.getValue(), node.getNodeName());
                }
                break;
            }

            // for attributes of this node
            NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
            if (!(attributes == null || attributes.getLength() == 0)) {
                for (int i = 0, count = attributes.getLength(); i < count; ++i) {
                    Node attribute = attributes.item(i);
                    if (attribute != null) {
                        nodes.push(attribute);
                    }
                }
            }

            // for child nodes of this node
            NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
            if (!(childNodes == null || childNodes.getLength() == 0)) {
                for (int i = 0, count = childNodes.getLength(); i < count; ++i) {
                    Node childNode = childNodes.item(i);
                    if (childNode != null) {
                        nodes.push(childNode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // these will allow null values to be stored on a map so that we can distinguish
    // from values being on the map or not. map implementation returns null if the there
    // is no map element with a given key. If the value is null there is no way to
    // distinguish from value not being on the map or value being null. these classes
    // remove ambiguity.
    private static class Holder<T> {

        protected final T value;

        public Holder(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public T getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Holder<?> other = (Holder<?>) obj;
            if (value == null) {
                if (other.value != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }

    private static class Key<T> extends Holder<T> {

        public Key(T value) {
            super(value);
        }

    }

    private static class Value<T> extends Holder<T> {

        public Value(T value) {
            super(value);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of traversing the DOM tree it is easier to iterate the `NodeList` returned by `document.getElementsByTagName("*")`.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to setting the prefix, you must also *declare* your namespace somewhere.

[EDIT] If you look into the package `org.w3c.dom`, you'll notice that there is no support for namespaces whatsoever except that you can create a Document node with a namespace URI:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
DOMImplementation DOMImplementation = builder.getDOMImplementation();
Document doc = DOMImplementation.createDocument(
    "http://www.somecompany.com/2005/xyz", // namespace
    "root",
    null /*DocumentType*/);

Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
root.setPrefix("xyz");
root.setAttribute(
    "xmlns:xyz",
    "http://www.somecompany.com/2005/xyz");
```

With the standard W3C DOM API of Java 5 (and up), it's not possible to *modify* the namespace of a node.

But the W3C DOM API is just a couple of interfaces. So what you should try is to look at the implementation (i.e. the actual class of your document instance), cast it to the real type. This type should have additional methods and if you're lucky, you can use those to modify the namespace.

Comment: Good, where? Document.declareNamespaceSomewhere(...) donesn't exist ;)

Comment: Correct, this is not part of W3C's DOM API. See my edits for a way out.

Comment: Thank you. The problem here is: I create a new document, the way you described, **with** a root element (without it doesn't work, thanks DOM). So now I would have to copy sub-nodes of the existing document to the new one, right? Would it be enought to ensure a **full** copy?

Comment: To copy nodes, you must first remove them from the source document and then add them to the target document. That way, everything should be preserved. If you omit the remove, you'll get "node already has a parent" errors.

Comment: And you're right: Namespaces are already hard enough and the W3C API sure doesn't help to make them any more simple.

Answer (score 5):

Well, here goes the recursive "solution":
*(I still hope that someone might find a better way to do this)*

```
public static void renameNamespaceRecursive(Document doc, Node node,
        String namespace) {

    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        System.out.println("renaming type: " + node.getClass()
            + ", name: " + node.getNodeName());
        doc.renameNode(node, namespace, node.getNodeName());
    }

    NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); ++i) {
        renameNamespaceRecursive(doc, list.item(i), namespace);
    }
}
```

Seems to work, although I don't know if **it's correct to rename only the node type
ELEMENT_NODE**, or if other node types must be renamed.

Answer (score 1):

we can change the xml namespace using sax parser, try this

```
import java.util.ListIterator;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.Namespace;
import org.dom4j.QName;
import org.dom4j.Visitor;
import org.dom4j.VisitorSupport;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;

public class VisitorExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = new SAXReader().read("test.xml");
    Namespace oldNs = Namespace.get("oldNamespace");
    Namespace newNs = Namespace.get("newPrefix", "newNamespace");
    Visitor visitor = new NamespaceChangingVisitor(oldNs, newNs);
    doc.accept(visitor);
    System.out.println(doc.asXML());
  }
}

class NamespaceChangingVisitor extends VisitorSupport {
  private Namespace from;
  private Namespace to;

  public NamespaceChangingVisitor(Namespace from, Namespace to) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
  }

  public void visit(Element node) {
    Namespace ns = node.getNamespace();

    if (ns.getURI().equals(from.getURI())) {
      QName newQName = new QName(node.getName(), to);
      node.setQName(newQName);
    }

    ListIterator namespaces = node.additionalNamespaces().listIterator();
    while (namespaces.hasNext()) {
      Namespace additionalNamespace = (Namespace) namespaces.next();
      if (additionalNamespace.getURI().equals(from.getURI())) {
        namespaces.remove();
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This solution only works with dom4j Document, not w3c Document.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation of Ivan's original post worked for me: setting the attribute on the document node.

```
xslRoot.setAttribute("xmlns:fo", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format");
```

where

- *xslRoot* is the document/root element/node,
- *fo* is the namespace ID

Hope that helps someone!

Mike Watts

Comment: Setting the "xmlns" attribute doesn't actually change the namespace. Try calling the `getNamespaceURI()` method

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using the Xerces classes, you can create a DOMParser that replaces the URI of attributes and elements with your fixed up URIs:

```
import org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser;

public static class MyDOMParser extends DOMParser {
    private Map<String, String> fixupMap = ...;

    @Override
    protected Attr createAttrNode(QName attrQName)
    {
        if (fixupMap.containsKey(attrQName.uri))
            attrQName.uri = fixupMap.get(attrQName.uri);
        return super.createAttrNode(attrQName);
    }

    @Override
    protected Element createElementNode(QName qName)
    {
        if (fixupMap.containsKey(qName.uri))
            qName.uri = fixupMap.get(qName.uri);
        return super.createElementNode(qName);
    }       
}
```

The elsewhere, you can parse the

```
DOMParse p = new MyDOMParser(...);
p.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
Document doc = p.getDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've got your Document instance..

```
import org.dom4j.*;

{

    static final String         YOUR_NAMESPACE_PREFIX =   "PREFIX"; 
    static final String         YOUR_NAMESPACE_URI    =   "URI"; 

    Document document = ...

    //now get the root element
    Element element = document.getRootElement();
    renameNamespaceRecursive(element);
    ...

    //End of this method
}

//the recursive method for the operation
void renameNamespaceRecursive(Element element) {
    element.setQName(new QName(element.getName(), DocumentHelper.createNamespace(YOUR_NAMESPACE_PREFIX, YOUR_NAMESPACE_URI)));
    for (Iterator i  = element.elementIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        renameNamespaceRecursive((Element)i.next());
    }
}
```

That should do.

Answer (score -1):

I solved using org.jdom.Element:

Java:

```
import org.jdom.Element;
...
Element kml = new Element("kml", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
```

XML:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">; 
...
</kml>
```

Comment: The question is about an already created DOM Document, so this approach cannot work. JDOM is not DOM.