# Java DOM, namespace / version problem

Tags: java, xml, dom, namespaces

Im in the process of creating XML as a Node for a RMI program I am developing but I have run across a problem. I can create the XML using DOM but I am struggling to add namespace and version to the top of my XML. I have tried using setAttribute and setAttributeNS but at the moment lost in what else I can do.

The java code to create the element is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

            Node root = doc.createElement("Request");
            doc.appendChild(root);

//code ommited
```

The result I get currently is:

```
<Request>
    <Identification>
        <UserID>user</UserID>
        <Password>pass</Password>
    </Identification>
</Request>
```

In the request section I need it to look like:

```
<Request xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="URL" Version="1.0">
```

Any help will be appreciated to help solve this issue!

Thanks

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492428/javadom-how-do-i-set-the-base-namespace-of-an-already-created-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd want something like:

```
...
Element root = doc.createElement("Request");
root.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "URL");
root.setAttribute("Version", "1.0");
doc.appendChild(root);
...
```

Defining `root` as an `Element` gives you the .setAttribute* methods.

This would give you

```
<Request Version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="URL"/>
```

I know that includes a bit more, but the xmlns:xsi attribute is needed so that the xsi namespace is defined.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was trying before but Instead of Element root I was using Node root which was throwing errors. Makes sense now!