# How to serialize XML without xmlns attributes?

Tags: javascript, dom, scala.js

My code is in Scala.js, but I think the gist of it should be easy to understand from a JavaScript perspective:

```
  def htmlToXHTML(input: String)
  (implicit parser: DOMParser, serializer: XMLSerializer): String = {
    val doc = parser.parseFromString(input, "text/html")
    val body = getElementByXpath("/html/body", doc).singleNodeValue
    val bodyXmlString = serializer.serializeToString(body)
    val xmldoc = parser.parseFromString(bodyXmlString, "application/xml")
    val xmlDocElems: NodeList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("*")
    xmlDocElems.foreach{
      case elem: Element =>
        elem.removeAttribute("xmlns")
        println(s"Found element $elem with html: ${elem.outerHTML}")
      case node => println(s"Warning: found unexpected non-element node: $node.")
    }
    xmldoc.firstElementChild.innerHTML
  }
```

This is used above, so including it for completeness (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284815/3096687):

```
  def getElementByXpath(xpath: String, doc: Document): XPathResult =
    doc.evaluate(
      xpath, doc, null.asInstanceOf[XPathNSResolver],
      XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null
    )
```

In short, this function reads an HTML string, converts it to an HTML document, serializes to XML, reparses as XML, and finds all the elements in the doc and loops over them (`foreach`), and then removes the `xmlns` attribute. It seems that the resulting innerHTML, however, still has the `xmlns` attributes on elements, even though the first `println` (aka `console.log`) indicates we are finding the elements in question, but not removing the `xmlns` attributes.

The problem may derive from [default values](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/met_element_removeattribute.asp) specified in a DTD:

> If a default value for the attribute is defined in a DTD, a new attribute immediately appears with the default value

Comment: I just tried `elem.setAttribute("xmlns", "")` instead of remove, but the result is weird: `<a0:br xmlns:a0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="" />` - I guess it doesn't deal well with the lack of namespace.

Comment: You misunderstand how the DOM API works. The element's qualified name still includes its namespace URI, even if you remove the xmlns attribute. Think of the xmlns attribute as a cross-check of the namespace URI, rather than the namespace URI itself.

Comment: @Alohci, thanks, yeah I guess I understood that at some level, and that this is ultimately more an issue of serialization format (but `XMLSerializer` does not appear to be configurable, so I was trying to work around that)

Answer (score 3):

I probably would cheat and remove the `xmlns` from the resulting string, as it's a [huge pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316791/how-can-i-change-the-namespace-on-every-node-in-a-dom) to make the elements lose their namespace.

If you insist on doing that, you could try building a document from scratch while walking the original DOM -- pedantically copying everything but the namespaces (i.e. using createElementNS with an empty namespace?)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, the easiest is to remove it from the result string:

```
xmls.serializeToString(domNode).replace(/xmlns="[^"]+"/, '')
```